# Converting arduino serial readings into float or int on the raspberry pi with python3

Tags: python-3.x, casting, arduino, pyserial

I have a serial connection between my **raspberry pi** and my **arduino**. I can send data from **arduino** to the **pi** but when I try to convert the receiving data into a **int** or a **float** I get an error message.

Let's say I try to send the number *35* to the **pi**, and try to convert it on the **python** side I get following message:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10:''

and when I try to convert it to **float** I get the following message:

> could not convert string to float.

I'm using **Idle 3.5.3** on the **raspberry pi**. I tried many things I've seen in this forum: like `strip()` but nothing seems to work. What could be wrong?

Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  Serial.println(35);

  delay(5000);


}
```

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import serial
from array import array
import csv

arduino = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyACM0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
)
arduino.flushInput()


print("test")

while 1:
       incoming = arduino.readline().decode('ascii').strip()
       float(incoming)
       print(incoming)
```

I expected a cast to **int** or **float** but I get only error messages

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
incoming = arduino.readline().decode('ascii')
    if not incoming is "":

            if int(incoming.strip()) == 1:
                    data.append(float(arduino.readline().decode('ascii').strip())/100)
```